# PropTypes in react es6 doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I created a component and want to validate one of its property. But it seems the validation doesn't work. When I access this component, I always got below property undefined error:

> Cannot read property '*map*' of undefined

Below is my component definition.

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'
import Carousel from 'nuka-carousel'

export default class DiagnosticSchedule extends Component {

  render() {
    let {style, diagnostics, afterSlide, beforeSlide} = this.props
    // if(diagnostics === undefined){
    //   return (<div/>)
    // }
    return (
      <div style={style}>
        <Carousel style={style} decorators={null} afterSlide={afterSlide} beforeSlide={beforeSlide}>
          {
            diagnostics.map(diagnostic => {
              return (
                <div style={styles.message}>
                  {diagnostic.name}
                </div>
              )
            })
          }
        </Carousel>

      </div>
    )
  }


}

DiagnosticSchedule.propTypes = {
  diagnostics: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};


const styles = {
  carousel:{

  },
  message: {
    fontSize: 'xx-large',
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    lineHeight: '5',
    zIndex: 100,
    width: '100%',
    textAlign: 'center',
  }
}
```

I think below code is used to validate this component's property.

```
DiagnosticSchedule.propTypes = {
  diagnostics: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

but it still complains that **the diagnostics is an undefined object**.

Do I miss anything or do I misunderstand the PropTypes validation? What is the expected behavior of PropTypes?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `getDefaultProps()` try setting `DiagnosticSchedule.defaultProps = {...}`.

Comment: yes, it works. I wander what does DiagnosticSchedule.propTypes do here. If I don't have DiagnosticSchedule.defaultProps my code will produce issues.

Comment: `getDefaultProps()` works only with `React.createClass`.

Comment: I understand getDefaultProps() now. What I don't understand is DiagnosticSchedule.propTypes. What is it used for?

Comment: `DiagnosticSchedule.propTypes` declares what kind of props your component expects. If you break that contract, it will give a warning if you run React in development mode. See the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html).

Comment: so that means propTypes has no impact for production mode.

Comment: `propTypes` won't be checked in production mode, correct.

Comment: Thanks could you answer this question so I can accept it.

Comment: Yeah. I set up a basic answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens because the `diagnostics` prop doesn't get a default value. If you don't pass the prop, it will be set to `undefined`. To fix the situation, you can set `defaultProps` like this:

```
DiagnosticSchedule.defaultProps = {
    diagnostics: []
};
```